# Negative margin not giving desired effect

Tags: css, slider, margin

I have just inserted a slider in to a site, with a negative top margin of -13px on the wrapper div so that it is slightly underneath a semi-transparent white bar (which has higher z-index) and in Opera it looks fine.

However in Firefox, IE and Chrome, the negative margin doesn't seem to have an effect and the semi-transparent white bar is just showing the white background behind, if I remove "overflow: hidden;" from the wrapper div then the slider moves up but this breaks the actual slider re-positioning the slides halfway across the screen etc..

The slider is the revolution slider plugin and this is a Wordpress site (though didn't post this question in the Wordpress stackoverflow site as it's not related to Wordpress core functions, simply a CSS issue i presume?).

Slider can be seen here: http://tinyurl.com/qjumkt8

Comment: give your #header overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @webkit for the solution, I also managed to get it working by changing overflow: hidden to visible on both the slider wrapper and the child div but webkit's solution is much simpler.